# Global exception for AppContainerLoopback filter in WFP

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

So I learned today that UWP apps (which are being ran in AppContainers) do not have access to localhost at all. So if I run a native win32 app that listens to `127.0.0.1:555` I cannot make that connection from UWP app (unless it is started in the context of the same AppContainer).

Long explanation for this is [apparently here](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2021/08/understanding-network-access-windows-app.html) but you need 30 years of experience and 7 bachelor degrees to understand it.

```
Name       : AppContainerLoopback
Action Type: Block
Key        : 0740183e-bc32-4cac-b9a7-584c568a1823
Id         : 126355
Description: AppContainerLoopback
Layer      : FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_RECV_ACCEPT_V4
Sub Layer  : MICROSOFT_DEFENDER_SUBLAYER_WSH
Flags      : None
Weight     : 18446744073709551614
Conditions :
FieldKeyName               MatchType   Value
------------               ---------   -----
FWPM_CONDITION_FLAGS       FlagsAllSet IsLoopback
FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_USER_ID Equal       O:LSD:(A;;CC;;;AC)(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-3-1)(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-3-2)(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-3-3)(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-…

<Owner> : NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
<DACL>
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES: (Allowed)(None)(Match)
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\Your Internet connection: (Allowed)(None)(Match)
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\Your Internet connection, including incoming connections from the Internet: (Allowed)(None)(Match)
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\Your home or work networks: (Allowed)(None)(Match)
NAMED CAPABILITIES\Proximity: (Allowed)(None)(Match)
```

My question is simple: **how can I either disable this filter or add a global allowance with higher priority?** It is a very "sanitized" machine, no security considerations here.

P.S. I've already examined [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback), but it is applicable to my case, nor does it work even just for testing.

Comment: Kudos for linking the article on AppContainers. Very interesting read. https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2021/08/understanding-network-access-windows-app.html

Comment: `CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt` command should serve your need. Please edit your question to specify the command you ran to add your app to the exempt list and the output you get after you list existing loopback exempts. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh780593(v=win.10)#enable-loopback-for-network-access